# ItemAnimator for RecyclerView does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-recyclerview

I want to use these animations to animate the items of RecyclerView:
https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

I have done everything that was required. However when I apply them nothing happens. What could be the problem?
I have included it in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:4.0.2'
}
```

And added to repositories:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
val recyclerView = view.recyclerView
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
recyclerView.itemAnimator = SlideInUpAnimator().apply {
addDuration = 350
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods

notifyItemChanged(int)
notifyItemInserted(int)
notifyItemRemoved(int)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)

and set adapter in this way

recyclerView.adapter = AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter)